# Create simple ListView in Android

Tags: android, xml, listview

This is my `MenuFragment`. In this i have the `ListView`, and here i don't have any errors.

```
   package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;
import dk.appografen.joeandthejuice.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Arrays;  
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;  
import android.widget.ListView;  

public class MenuFragment extends Fragment{  

private ListView mainListView ;  
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;
View rootView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menukort, container,
        false);

return rootView;

}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

// Find the ListView resource.   
mainListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  

// Create and populate a List of planet names.  
String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",  
                              "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};    
ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();  
planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );  

// Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.  
getActivity();

// Add more planets. If you passed a String[] instead of a List<String>   
// into the ArrayAdapter constructor, you must not add more items.   
// Otherwise an exception will occur.  
listAdapter.add( "Ceres" );  
listAdapter.add( "Pluto" );  
listAdapter.add( "Haumea" );  
listAdapter.add( "Makemake" );  
listAdapter.add( "Eris" );  

// Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );  

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I see that you have extended `Activity` instead of extending `Fragment`. first thing you need to do is to change this line `public class MenuFragment extends Activity` to `public class MenuFragment extends Fragment`. now the following steps are little bit complicated because you have to move some of your code to `onCreateView()` method and some of it to `onViewCreated` from the `onCreate` method. I like to do this following way firstly in your `onCreateView` method just inflate the fragment using the LayoutInflater and then perform all other actions such as setting adapters, instantiating widgets or subviews (listview, gridview, etc.) in `onViewCreated` method. Your code will look somewhat like below.

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;
import dk.appografen.joeandthejuice.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Arrays;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;  
import android.widget.ListView;  

public class MenuFragment extends Fragment{  

private ListView mainListView ;  
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;
View rootView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menukort, container,
            false);

    return rootView;

}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Find the ListView resource.   
    mainListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  

    // Create and populate a List of planet names.  
    String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",  
                                  "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};    
    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();  
    planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );  

    // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.  
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);  

    // Add more planets. If you passed a String[] instead of a List<String>   
    // into the ArrayAdapter constructor, you must not add more items.   
    // Otherwise an exception will occur.  
    listAdapter.add( "Ceres" );  
    listAdapter.add( "Pluto" );  
    listAdapter.add( "Haumea" );  
    listAdapter.add( "Makemake" );  
    listAdapter.add( "Eris" );  

    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );  

}

}
```

Comment: Hi. I have tried what you said and imported the things i needed. Now i got an error in this: listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);  Saying: The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(MenuFragment, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined

Comment: change `this` to `getActivity()` and try again. let me know if it works.

Comment: The getActivity() fixed the error. But in my TabsPagerAdapter i still get error in: return new MenuFragment(); 
Like before?

Comment: are you using support library? as if appcompat-v7 or v4? if yes then you need to import `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` not `import android.app.Fragment`

Comment: okk I see as you are using TabsPagerAdapter so you must be using appcompat support library and in that case your all fragments need to import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. change this and let me know if any more errors persist ..

Comment: Correct. I am using libs. I changed it, got no error, but when i try to run the fragment/activity on my phone, it shuts down?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56131/discussion-between-setu-and-chrfugl).